# How to filter defect results by a single story

Tags: java, rally, defects

This query return defects from a single project:

```
QueryRequest defects = new QueryRequest("defect");
defects.setProject("https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/project/5022032422.js");
```

I would like to narrow down the result to a single story.  Basically return defects associated with a single story. How can I do that?

Comment: I have tried setting up filter --------------------------------------Map<String, QueryFilter> filters = new HashMap<String, QueryFilter>();
  filters.put("State", new QueryFilter("State", "=", "Submitted"));
  filters.put("Requirement", new QueryFilter("Requirement", "=", "Automation Regression for Product X"));
  QueryFilter complexFilter = filters.get("State").and(filters.get("Requirement"));
  defects.setQueryFilter(complexFilter);

Answer (score 1):

Check out the WSAPI docs here: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

You can see that Defect has a field called Requirement that represents its attached story.
You can use that field in your query, specifying the desired story's ref as the value:

```
defects.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Requirement", "=", "/hierarchicalrequirement/12345"));
```

Comment: Great!  If you could please mark this as the answer that would be great.  It better helps us track which questions have been answered and helps other stackoverflow users find answers more quickly.